# jquery change image path on div hover and make its class active?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div structure like this :-

```
<div class="row margin-bottom-20">
    <div class="col-md-3 service-box-v1" id="div1">
        <div><a href="#"><img src="path" id="img1" /></a></div>
        <h2>abc</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 service-box-v1" id="div2">
        <div><a href="#"><img src="path" id="img2" /></a></div>
        <h2>def</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 service-box-v1" id="div3">
        <div><a href="#"><img src="path" id="img3" /></a></div>
        <h2>ghi</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 service-box-v1" id="div4">
        <div><a href="#"><img src="path" id="img5"></a></div>
        <h2>jkh</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

On pageload I want to assign class active to div1 and change img1 path and when user hovers on div2 its class become active and img2 path changes and div1 active class removes and img1 comes to its old source.

I ave tried this :-

```
 $("#div1").mouseover(function () {
        old_src = $("#img1").attr("src");
        $("#img1").attr("src", "path");
    }).mouseout(function () {
        $("#img1").attr("src", old_src);

    });
```

But in this case I have to do this for every div. I need suggesions for a generic code rather than doing this for every div seperately.

Comment: what you have tried so far???

Comment: simple solution would be set as `background-image` and change it on `hover`

Comment: @Vitorino Fernandes Image is not a background Image of a div see my div structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, its a start where you can add the rest of the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Set first service box element active
    var firstElem = $('.service-box-v1:first-child');
    firstElem.addClass('active');

    // Change src image
    firstElem.find('img').attr('src', 'new_path');

    // Add hover event
    $('.service-box-v1').on('hover', function() {
        // Reset all active classes
        $('.service-box-v1').removeClass('active');

        // Add active class + change src image
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $(this).find('img').attr('src', 'new_path');
    });
});
```